# how to make these two div left and right

Tags: html, css

I have this html

```
  <body>

    <div id="onlineBookingDiv" style="float: right; position:fixed; right:0px; width:40%">
  //content here    
</div>
    <div class="zumaContent" id="zumaContent">
//content here    
</div>

    </body>
```

The first one is at the right, but the second one is not at the top left, it is just on the left.

I want to make the second one on the top left

#### i hope you got me, if not, tell me to make photo

Comment: Your HTML doesn't show anything.. please post complete one with close divs `</div>`.  a photo will be good idea too

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have both floated or you want them to be sticky containers?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you make 2 divs and give one CSS property `float:left` and for another give `float:right`. and to clear the floating you give it `overflow:hidden` to parent div or an extra div element after the floats (empty) with the`clear:both` CSS property which will make the lay-out to not go out of the flow.

Check the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/rigakeqi/1/)**.

```
div{height:200px; width:200px; border:1px solid gray}
.one{float:left;}
.two{float:right;}

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see the parent container in your code example.

Comment: but the first dive, which is in the right, has a table and that table needs to have overflow: scrol attribute

Comment: I haven't added  in my Demo. because I don't need to add `overflow:hidden` in the Demo. This is the reason I explained in question he can either use `overflow:hidden` or `clear:both`.

Comment: Clear floats without overflow: hidden - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: why downvote sir? explain please. This is just because the question was not clear and I gave my suggestion so early..

Comment: His question is about position fixed not floats basically.

Comment: but with this answer he will achieve the same thing; an he is not going to lost anywhere. he is just setting the position using `position` value and I suggested to use `float`.

Comment: From the question I still can't understand clearly what @MarcoDinatsoli want.  I wish if he can provide an image or photo to make it more clear.

Comment: you are just making assumption, what he want. What if someone giving him a another solution. so if I am giving him a another solution you are treating here as a judge..

Comment: I never give anyone down voting. but I found some people here are always try to be smart and treat themselves like a judge.. How could they judge even the question is not clear or incomplete.

Comment: @Sultan I agree with you. but don't know what the problem with Johan.

Comment: When you give an answer it should give correct information as well. If you mention clearing floats show it in your code example. To clear the floats with clear: both this should be an empty element after the floated elements. Update your answer and I will upvote it. I corrected your answer and upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this is what you need:

**CSS:**

```
`.boxWrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#onlineBookingDiv
{
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    width:40%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#zumaContent{
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width:40%;
    background-color: #eee;
}`
```

**HTML:**

`<div class="boxWrapper">
    <div id="onlineBookingDiv">BOX 1</div>
    <div class="zumaContent" id="zumaContent">BOX 2</div>
</div>`

See this **[E X A M P L E](http://jsfiddle.net/A9LqN/1/)** please

Answer (score 0):

In your example you use fixed positioning on one element. A fixed positioned element will make it stick relative to the document. Thus it is normal your other element is not.
It all depends whether you want this behaviour or not?
Otherwise see the other answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/pP3YE/

```
#onlineBookingDiv {
    position:fixed; 
    right:0; 
    width:40%;
    background: red;
}
.zumaContent {
    position:fixed;
    width:40%;
    background: green;
}
```